# Which event fires when i click outside paper-dialog?

Tags: polymer

I want to catch dismiss event of paper-dialog box.

Is there any event which fires on tab out / outside dialog box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `core-overlay-close-completed`.

Please see this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ripaho/3/edit).

Comment: Thanks Justin! I tried observe as well and it works well. Will it be able to handle multiple dialog? I mean what if I Toggle one more dialog on current paper-dialog - then event will trigger for last dialog as well, right?

Comment: This logic is deprecated with the release of Polymer 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

As of the Polymer 1.0 release, you can do the following:

```
<paper-dialog id="loginDialog">
    ...
</paper-dialog>

var dialog = document.getElementById('loginDialog');
dialog.addEventListener('iron-overlay-closed', function (customEvent) {
    var id = customEvent.currentTarget.id;
    console.log(id + " is closed!");
});
```

The `customEvent` has many different properties that allow you to see which dialog you are coming from. The example above looks at the `Id` of the `currentTarget` field.

In the `paper-dialog-behaviors.html` we see that the following events can be listened to:

```
listeners: {
  'click': '_onDialogClick',
  'iron-overlay-opened': '_onIronOverlayOpened',
  'iron-overlay-closed': '_onIronOverlayClosed'
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried another (after suggested by @justin) approach to get triggered:

```
  observe: {
    '$.dialog.opened': 'dialogChanged'
  },
  dialogChanged: function (old, new) {
    console.log(new);
  },
```

I see, `opened` attribute with dialog and it changed depending on dialog status.

Comment: Both answers here do not work anymore in Polymer 1.0.