# Is there an "onOpen" event for paper-dialog?

Tags: javascript, events, polymer, paper-elements

Is there an "onOpen" event for `paper-dialog`? I would like to know when the dialog is fully "opened" and "closed", mostly for changing content when the dialog has finishing its opening animation.

Previously [in Polymer 0.5 one can listen to the `core-overlay-close-completed` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761284/which-event-fires-when-i-click-outside-paper-dialog) for that. However it doesn't seem to be working in 1.0, even when I changed `core-overlay` to `iron-overlay`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to inherit `iron-overlay-behavior` which fires the [`iron-overlay-opened` and `iron-overlay-closed` events](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-overlay-behavior/blob/master/iron-overlay-behavior.html#L140).

Comment: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-overlay-behavior?active=Polymer.IronOverlayBehavior

Comment: That's weird, how did you get to that page from the catalog? The one I was seeing before doesn't contain the "Events" part: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-overlay-behavior

Comment: Starting from the `paper-dialog` page https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dialog I scrolled down to Behaviors and clicked on `Polymer.PaperDialogBehavior`.  From there I scrolled down again to Behaviors and clicked `Polymer.IronOverlayBehavior`.

Comment: I really wish those nested behaviors would inline their documentation with whatever components they're applied to.  Just mix in the properties and events and such with a little tag saying "inherited from `FooBehavior`" or something.  It would have made it much easier for you to find those events.

Comment: True, I have spent near an hour trying to figure out how to do this and looking over the whole documentation, but I have never thought of clicking those links at the bottom to get there.

Comment: It's a high-priority task for the Polymer team to get the inherited properties visible directly in the documentation. It will be available there eventually.

Comment: @ScottMiles that's great to hear!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I also wanted to say that it's been a challenge to follow the Polymer documentation. Looking forward to improvements and thanks for the comment, @ScottMiles!